# Add text to 3D cube with HelixToolkit.Sharpdx.Core

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, helix-3d-toolkit

I am using HelixToolkit on a WPF (.net core) application.
I've set up a Viewport3Dx with a cube inside like so:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:hx="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf/SharpDX"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <hx:Viewport3DX  x:Name="Viewport3Dx"
                     Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     Background="White"
                     BackgroundColor="White"
                     Title="SharpDXView"
                     ShowCoordinateSystem="False">
        <hx:AmbientLight3D Color="#515151" />
        <hx:DirectionalLight3D Direction="-0.5, -1, -0.2"
                               Color="White" />
    </hx:Viewport3DX>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
using HelixToolkit.SharpDX.Core;
using HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace Test1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Viewport3Dx.Camera = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.PerspectiveCamera();
            Viewport3Dx.Camera.Position = new Point3D(5, 0, 0);
            Viewport3Dx.Camera.LookAt(new Point3D(0, 0, 0), 0);
            Viewport3Dx.EffectsManager = new DefaultEffectsManager();

            var mb = new MeshBuilder();
            mb.AddCube();

            var meshGeometry = new MeshGeometryModel3D
            {
                Material = PhongMaterials.Green,
                Transform = Transform3D.Identity,
                Geometry = mb.ToMeshGeometry3D()
            };

            Viewport3Dx.Items.Add(meshGeometry);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I would like to add some text to every side of the cube (in the center). The text should be on the cubes' surface. If possible I would like to not use a texture, because the cube might have different side lengths later.

Answer (score -1):

Texture coordinate is not affected by cube side length as long as your model is a cube.

Comment: Each side can have different side lengths (e.g. a cuboid). While it still is a cube in HelixToolKit terms.